# change href value on page load without adding classes

Tags: javascript, href, getelementbyid, getelementsbytagname

I am trying to overwrite an old link that is written into some code via a CMS, therefore I cannot access the base code easily.

I am trying to add a script that will overwrite the current link with a new one.

Here is my code:

script:

```
function linkChange() {

    var links = document.getElementById("titlecontent");
    links.getElementsByTagName("a").href = "http://www.cnn.com/";

}
```

or

```
function linkChange() {

    document.getElementById("titlecontent").getElementsByTagName("a").href = "http://www.cnn.com/";

}
```

html:

```
<ul id="titlecontent"><a href="link_to_change"><li>link</li></a></ul>
```

The main issue is I cannot go in and add an id or class to the `<a>` tag, so I need to target it starting with the `<ul>` which has the id "titlecontent".

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` is a node **list** not a single node

Comment: so i need to add a node position? getElementsByTagName("a")[0]

Comment: that would change the first (or only) one

Comment: as a side note, switch your a and li elements, it should always go ul > li

Comment: @aw04 i cant :( its an old CMS and the html converter writes out the code, but i will keep this in mind for future developing!

Answer (score 1):

This works :

```js
document.getElementById("titlecontent").getElementsByTagName("a")[0].href = "http://www.cnn.com/";
```

```html
<ul id="titlecontent"><a href="link_to_change"><li>link</li></a></ul>
```

The problem was that you needed to select a specific element in `getElementsByTagName`, because it returns a list of elements, not just one.

Comment: thank you everyone- this works perfectly.   I will accept the answer once the 8 mins are up.